How can I explain this mental power scientifically?
Related to my previous question- 'A "Rational" Explanation for psychic/psionic abilities', this question would focus on a 'logical' (non-magic) explanation for a more specific power- Psychic or Psycho-projection, i.e. the ability to cause objects (or possibly living beings, if one is gifted enough in this particular discipline) one imagines to take on physical form outside of his mind.
How can I rationally explain how this ability works?

Try not to have your abilities be rooted in science as too much explaining might ruin suspension of disbelief or bore your readers. It is best to try and use the ability in scientific ways instead of having the ability be explained scientifically.

The construction of multiple competing hypotheses. Test these hypotheses to see which ones don't fit. See what's left, then construct more competing hypotheses.... rinse and repeat until any hypothetical creator comes along and confirms - or tells you "Nope." then walks away giggling. At present any answer would be on a "best guess" basis of a phenomenon never seen - this would lead to a host of opinion-based answers. Not ideal, I'm sure you agree. Examples might include: Fiddler's Green by Richard McKenna, elements of M.K. Joseph’s “The Hole in the Zero”.

Full text available here: Fiddler's Green (RMcK). Naturally it drifts away from scientific explanations as it baffles those who experience it. They do however figure out the rules at play.

I am sorry but I do not understand the text of the question.

I think it's important to clearly define what your ability does and how it works, but that "how" should never go much deeper than a functional description. at some point you have to say "that's just the way it is" and the deeper the level you do that at, the harder it is to for you make your ability consistent and logical. Think about what kind of concentration and mental processes are required, the amount of time it takes, the limits to it. Don't think about "there's this psychic particle which responds to specific neural patterns and which can manipulate energy based on those patterns".

Because really, any "scientific" explanation you can come up with will be complete gobbledygook. I've been there, and eventually it just gets tiring trying to think of all the edge cases and complexities of making it "real".

VTC:Opinion-Based. We requently get questions asking for help scientifically rationalizing some form of (often godlike) magic. The problem, of course, is that magic isn't scientific. Any answer is an opinion (at best), which means the question cannot have an objectively chosen best answer - a requirement of Stack Exchange (see the [help]). Worse, you want to rationalize, what, bringing mass together to manifest an object like a sculpture (telekinesis) or reflected/refracted light (photokinesis) or manipulating the other mind(s) such that they believe they're seeing something (telepathy)? ...

... my point is that you haven't described this power at all, and yet you want us to spitball how it can be scientifically explained. I will be happy to retract my vote if (a) you explain how the power works outside the mind in excruciating detail and (b) you explain how you'll judge a best answer. (BTW, keep in mind that science is a harsh task master. The odds are excellent that science will require energy consumption for this power well beyond the limits of human endurance.)

We dont know
Consider this:
We absolutely know about Alzheimer's Disease.
We can infer it via testing and observing cognitive decline that exceeds what is typical for someone of that age etc. Although an exact diagnosis requires the Brain tissue to be examined (after death)
But as for the mechanism as to how or why?
We simply don't know.
And this is not limited to just Alzheimers - there are many phenomena where we can observe something happening, we know definitively (using the scientific method) that it is happening...
And we have absolutely no clue as to how or why

Great answer.  One thing I would add is that when building worlds that are meant to include "magic" that feels scientific, it's good use a hard magic system.  Hard magic systems follow a discrete set of rules that always works the same way every time.  So, if psychics are consistent in what they can/can't do, it feels a lot more scientific than if your characters are always solving ad hoc problems with thier abilities and then not being able to solve similar other problems with them.

They have a nanite swarm inside them.
When they will an object creation, the nanites within them use ambient material to create the object, relying on trace amounts of deuterium to power fusion reactors.
The original intent of this was to allow an alien lifeform to colonize a new planet. Their ship crashed, and a random native with a compatible genetic code found their crashed ship. Now, some people can use the nanite swarms to do psycho-projection.

Simulated Reality
In our world (assuming that it is not a simulation), such abilities are imposible  according the the known laws of physics and our current understanding of biology.  I'm not saying it can't be possible, just that there is no known mechanism that would make it possible. But, in a simulated reality that is exactly identical to our own, such abilities (and all sorts of other magic like stuff) could be a scientifically explainable.
Everything we know about science can be explained with some sort of computable data model, but computational data models can include parameters for handling non-standard functions/procedures that are not consistent with standard operation.  By the rules of a typical multi-user simulation, each user has permissions to do certain things, and not others.  So, you could think of a normal human being as being a basic user account with all the permissions they need to be able to interact with the world according to thier biological configuration.  They can walk, run, talk, etc.  And the laws of science are 100% consistent for them and everyone else around them who are basic users.  But the person(s) who made the simulation may have created escalated privileges for moderators, admins, bug testing, etc.
These people are literally not beholden to the same laws of science as everyone else because the powers that be who exist outside of, designed, and maintain the simulation have given them escalated permission to work by a different set of natural laws than everyone else... or at least, these powers SHOULD only belong to such chosen people.  If the creators are fallible, then the simulation could have bugs and exploits that would allow a common user to gain escalated privileges. So, use psychic powers with caution.  You don't want to get Admin smited for hacking or abusing your moderator privileges.

Due to Conservation of Mass, objects cannot be created out of nothing, so the ability as suggested is not possible with out current understanding of science and technology. However, there are few options for how this could work slightly differently.
You could invent a new piece of physics, and determine how your new physics could allow this ability. You would have to do the work to figure out the nuts and bolts, but you could essentially gain the benefits of having magic in your world, while keeping it somewhat plausible.
Another option would be to use sci-fi technology to replicate this effect. You can explain the technology in whatever level of detail you want. An example is you could have the objects be created by nanobot clouds, using mass from the ground. You could also use less realistic technologies, such as portals, holograms, or some quantum physics handwave.
If the effects are only temporary and the objects do not need to be physically created from mass, you could combine telekinesis and illusion abilities to allow the wielder to create illusory objects that are able to interact with real objects. You will still need to figure out how those two abilities work, but they're both probaby easier abilities to come up with an explanation for.
Any route you go with, keep in mind that defining the exact powers, limitations, and costs helps it to not become a story-breaking power. Additionally, many of these suggestions will have other consequences for your world. You can ignore the other implications, but they could also be a starting point for interesting worldbuilding.

You could get around Conservation of Mass by taking a bunch of particles from nearby rock or the ground or the atmosphere and rejigging them at sub-atomic level into whatever it is you're conjuring. However, doing this would probably require a lot of energy (my understanding of physics is way too rudimentary to even start guessing how much) so you'd run afoul of the Law of Conservation of Energy.

Sleight of hand
This is the usual mundane, scientific explanation for how a person could make things appear or disappear.
You could even make it way easier with super high tech active camouflage technology so the object is invisible until you, or an assistant also hidden by active camouflage, uncovers it.
